# NODE fs.readFile, JSON.parse and fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js

I'm writing an app in Node and have been running into a rare but detrimental occurrence.

So I have a schedule.txt and I write to it when the user makes a change but then also read it every second and then parse it for use throughout the program.

Rarely what happens is as a user is writing to the file (asynchronously) the app (based on the timer) reads the same file and attempts to parse it and fails.

I know from a design stand-point maybe this is just bound to happen... but I'm wondering if there is a quick fix I can do now. Would using writeFileSync help my situation? (make it more 'atomic'?) I just want to make sure that the app doesn't read the file while another process is still writing to the file.

TIA!

Niko

Comment: Generally, this is often handled with writing the file to a temp name, and then renaming it to the desired name.  A rename (on the same filesystem) is generally atomic.  If all of your reading and writing is happening in the same *process* why would you make the reader read the file vs. caching the contents internally?

Comment: ^ yeah thats the plan for ver2 haha (but not really laughing...)

Comment: For short term fix, just change them to synchronous reads and writes like you are thinking with writeFileSync and readFilesync.  This will work because node.js is single threaded, so if it's stuck doing reading, it CAN'T be writing, or vice versa.  In the long term, there are lots of design options you have that are much better than that though.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you'd want to serialize your read/writes. If it were me, I might try having a "manager" object which encapsulates the serialization, which you'd use like:

```
var fileManager = require('./file-manager');

// somewhere in the program
fileManager.scheduleWrite(data, function(err){
  // now the write is done
});

// somewhere else in the program
fileManager.scheduleRead(function(err, data){
  // `data` contains the data
});
```

Then implement it using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or a similar promises lib, like:

```
// in file-manager.js
var wait = Q();
module.exports = {
  scheduleWrite: function(data, cb){
    wait = wait.then(function(){
      // write data and call cb()
    });
  },
  scheduleRead: function(){
    wait = wait.then(function(){
      // read data and call cb(data)
    });
  }
};
```

The `wait` var will "stack up" into a serialized chain of tasks where the next one won't start until the previous one completes.